# How to count number of white pieces or patches accurately?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

Hi tried using this code for removing noise and blur.

```
J = double(imread('C:\Users\sai_praneeth7777\Desktop\project\real123.jpg'));
L= imnoise(J,'salt & pepper',0.02);
k = im2bw(I);
se=strel('disk',1);
bw=imopen(k,se);
imshow(bw);
cc = bwconncomp(bw,4);
number1  = cc.NumObjects;
display(number1);
BW1 = imfill(bw,'holes');
cc = bwconncomp(BW1,4);
number2  = cc.NumObjects;
figure;
imshow(L);
display(number2);
imshow(I);
```

Here is the original image
[image]

Here is the processed image
[image]

The problem is there is still some noise remaining and also some divisions are not clear,like in the top right the partitions are gone.I want to count number of white pieces so i will be getting wrong answer.I am new to matlab and image processing.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with a median filter, then you can make an opening a little bit bigger and then a small closing in order to regularize the contours. But as the borders are fuzzy, you cannot have a very precise/neat segmentation.

If you want to separate the different components, you can compute a distance map and use the local maxima in a watershed.

Comment: And btw, the number of maxima in the distance map will give you the number of pieces you want.